# JSF 1.2 - cannot access javax.el.ELContext

Tags: java, jsf

I got this error:

```
cannot access javax.el.ELContext
class file for javax.el.ELContext not found
```

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.20 and Mojarra JSF 1.2_13-b01-FCS. What class am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Why don't you stick to one account? http://www.google.com/search?q=icepax+site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers

Answer (score 7):

This class is present in the `jsp-api.jar` and `el-api.jar`. But it is included in Tomcat, so if you have added one of the two above jars on your classpath - remove them.